# Should my global variables, instances and singletons that I have in the Application class be static or not?

Tags: java, android

In my Android application I have a class that extends `Application` class and I'm storing some stuff there.

Let me just show the code:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

// Custom class to display toasts
public ToastMaker toastMaker = new ToastMaker();

// This class hashes passwords
public HashPassword hashPassword = new HashPassword();

// SQLite Database Handler
public DBTools dbTools;

// Declare the Universal Image Loader for lazy load of images
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

// Fonts
public Typeface font1;
public Typeface font2;

// Photo Handler custom class containing several methods that deal with images
public PhotoHandler photoHandler = new PhotoHandler(this);

// Bitmap Options
public BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions;

private static MyApplication singleton;

public MyApplication getInstance() {
    return singleton;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    singleton = this;


    // Setting up fonts
    try {
        font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), C.Fontz.FONT_1);
        font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), C.Fontz.FONT_2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Nothing can be done here
    }

    dbTools = DBTools.getInstance(this);

    // Create global configuration and initialize ImageLoader with this configuration
    // https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
    ImageLoaderConfiguration imageLoaderConfiguration = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(imageLoaderConfiguration);

    // Set global bitmap preferences
    bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bitmapOptions.inDither = false;
    bitmapOptions.inPurgeable = true;
    bitmapOptions.inInputShareable = true;
    bitmapOptions.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];


} // End of onCreate
```

And here is how I use something:

```
public MyApplication myApp;
myApp = (MyApp) getApplication();
```

and then, lets say I need some method of the PhotoHandler class

```
myApp.photoHandler.handlePhotos();
```

As far as I know everything is working fine, but somewhere I read some stuff mentioned about those being static. I'm not very good with the theory behind this, so am I fine this way or should I make those be static objects?

Comment: If development is something you're going to be doing any amount of, you should really take the 5 minutes or so it would take you to understand what `static` means. Otherwise you're going to be posting a lot of SO questions.

Comment: I have always had the impression that you should avoid static variables when possible. If your application works as is then I wouldn't mess with statics. The goal is to reduce scope to specificity, not to open scope as much as possible (even if it does make things "harder" for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since getAcpplication() returns your global application 'object', you don't need to make anything static in there.

And you will get the same 'global object' anywhere in your application where you use

```
myApp = (MyApp) getApplication();
```

So static variables/singletons are not required.

Answer (score 2):

It is totally ok to leave it like it is. You don't need to declare fields and methods static because all will run in the single Application instance that Android will manage.

Since this application is already similar to a Singleton, and because of the way you are accessing your application (correctly), you don't need this:

```
private static MyApplication singleton;

public MyApplication getInstance() {
    return singleton;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Application` class is already a singleton, and `onCreate()` is guaranteed to be called before everything else in your app. So, it's perfectly safe to write static getters like these :

```
public static MyApplication getInstance() {
    return singleton;
}

public static DBTools getDBTools() {
    return singleton.dbTools;
}
```

The only benefit is to shorten the code you have to write, but I saw some popular apps using it (including one from google).